# How does this R code/function creates a list with dataframes?

Tags: r

I saw this code in a function. 
Would appreciate if someone could break down this code and explain what it does.

```
assign(paste0(stock[i],'.f'),value = list(IS = temp1,BS = temp2,CF = temp3),envir = parent.frame()
```

Also, how do I modify the above code to have a dataframe with name of the of the stock and list name e.g. 'AAPL.f.IS'

Answer (score 0):

They are creating a variable outside the function (parent environment), to replicate, try this simple example:

```
foo <- function(i){
  assign(paste0(i,'.f'), value = list(IS = 1, BS = 3, CF = 3),
         envir = parent.frame()
  )

}

ls()
# [1] "foo"

foo("test")

ls()
# [1] "foo"    "test.f"

foo("test_again")

ls()
# [1] "foo"          "test.f"       "test_again.f"

str(test.f)
# List of 3
#  $ IS: num 1
#  $ BS: num 3
#  $ CF: num 3
```